# Searching for Processor and other information with Active Directory Search in Visual Basic

Tags: sql, vb.net

so I'm writing a script in VB to scan my network and return information on all of the computers it finds. So far I've been able to get Computer Names and all the OS information. I have:

```
Set objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection
objCommand.CommandText = _
    "Select Name, operatingSystem, operatingSystemVersion, operatingSystemServicePack from 'LDAP://DC=mydomain,DC=com' " _
        & "Where objectClass='computer'"  
objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 1000
objCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE 
Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute
```

Unfortunately, resources on the specific terminology to grab information like make, model, processor data, memory data, internet browser info, and so forth has been hard to find. Anyone know more about this than me? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried querying using WMI? Examples: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.11.heyscriptingguy.aspx#id0070011 and https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Retrieving-Hardware-bd39ff07

Comment: good advice! stumbled across some pretty good stuff and came up with a batch file that gets processor info. Would there be an easy way to throw my batch into the above code and have it run for each computer on the network? Sounds too good to be true.

Comment: The "Retrieving Hardware Inventory from Remote Computers" article has a section grabbing processor info ("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor"). You stated you are "able to get Computer Names" so you could write those to a .txt file and "Bam! Bob's your uncle." that script should work.